# Chrome strange click behavior on underlying element

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML code. While the screen is covered by the "cover" DIV, click on the button and somewhere else. The click not on the button does not fire. Later when the "cover" DIV is hidden the click on the button fires.

It appears as if there is a timing issue. Can someone please explain this behavior?

**Markup:**

```
<div id="cover"></div>
<button onclick="alert('Button clicked')">Click me</button>
<div id="text"></div>​
```

**CSS:**

```
#cover {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8
}​
```

**Javascript:**

```
function hide ()
{
    document.getElementById ("cover").style.display = "none";
}
function show ()
{
    document.getElementById ("cover").style.display = "block";
}
function busy (callback)
{
    show ();
    setTimeout (callback, 1);
}
function work ()
{
    var start = (new Date ()).getTime ();
    var wait  = 3000;
    while ((new Date()).getTime () - start < wait)
    {
        /* do nothing */
    }
    hide ();
}
function start ()
{
    document.getElementById ("cover").onclick = function (ev) {
        document.getElementById ("text").innerHTML = 'Cover clicked';
    };
    busy (work);
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/5DutW/4

Answer (score 4):

Your `work` function doesn't work (no pun intended): it will freeze the UI for 3 seconds, so clicks and other interactions will be queued up as you describe. Why don't you just pass `3000` to `setTimeout` instead of `1`?

```
function busy (callback)
{
    show ();
    setTimeout (callback, 3000);
}
function work ()
{
    hide ();
}
```

Comment: I suppose that was intended (to simulate some long-running script) because he already uses setTimeout in other functions.  But yes, whole scripting is processed in a single thread, so long running calculations will make page less responsive.  If you can, split such functions to smaller chunks and use `setTimeout(callback, 0)` to allow browsers to process stacked events.

Comment: @skalee Good advice. If that's really the problem the OP is trying to solve, it might be worthy looking into [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) too.

Comment: Actually in reality the delay is done by my server by using Ajax (the function "work" performs an Ajax call to the server) thus not by the Javascript code. The behavior is still the same. How come the click goes through the button when we see it behind the cover. Isn't it some sort of inconsistency between what we see and what is done.

Comment: @MarcK. I can't reproduce the issue you describe (see updated fiddle with changed work and busy functions - http://jsfiddle.net/5DutW/6/). When I first click on the button and the cover is visible, I just see the "cover clicked" message.

Comment: You changed the "work" function and it works, but in reality this function performs an Ajax call to the server and the delay is done by the server. Also my apology for mentioning Chrome. I tested it on Chromium 20.0, Firefox 17.0.1 and Safari on IPad2. The result are all the same.

Comment: Using Chrome 23 on OSX. Also tested in Firefox. Maybe I'm missing some step to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @MarcK. AJAX is asynchronous so it won't block (although you can enable synchronous behavior).  Could you post the piece of code you use for AJAX call for review?

Comment: I am using a synchronous call, e.g. xhr.open ("GET", url, false); xhr.send (null);

Comment: Ah, so that's it. Avoid synchronous calls, they have the same problem as the while loop you had (i.e., makes the UI unresponsive). I recommend an async call instead.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are locking the page thread:

```
while ((new Date()).getTime () - start < wait)
{
    /* do nothing */
}
```

This prevents events from being handled until it finishes, as well as prevent updates to the UI.

Why not just use a timeout instead? `setTimeout(hide,wait);`

Comment: In reality the function "work" performs an Ajax call and the delay is done by the server (some sort of sleep in C or PHP). Perhaps I should have explained that what really confuses me is that the click goes through the button while it is covered and the cover does not get the onclick event.

Answer (score 0):

After a number of tests, I can confirm this behavior. There is a big difference between Firefox and Chrome.

Keep in mind that, as many have said, a Javascript program is single-threaded.

In Firefox, when the function 'work' is performing the Ajax call, clicks are ignored. When the function returns and "cover" disappears, nothing happens.

In Chrome, the clicks are caught and queued. When the function 'work' returns, the onclick events are fired. Since "cover" has disappears, it does not get the onclick event. The button, on the other hand, receives the onclick event. For example, when I click on the button twice (when it was covered), later I get two alerts.

I find the Chrome behavior is confusing and IMHO wrong, because at the time I click my eyes naturally tells me that the button is covered thus can not be clicked (it doesn't appear as clicked button).

Thanks for all the answers and clues. I really appreciate it.